# How to increment counter in Ruby loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

For my Rails application I am trying to build a rake task that will populate the database with 10 `invoices` for each `user`:

```
def make_invoices
  User.all.each do |user|
    10.times do
      date = Date.today
      i = user.invoices.create!(:number => user.next_invoice_number,
                                :date   => date += 1.year)
      i.save
    end
  end
end
```

How can I increment the `date` by one year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
10.times do |t|
   puts t + 1 # will puts 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
end
```

And now you can set your year.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using [**`Date#next_year`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_year):

```
require 'date'

d = Date.today 
d # => #<Date: 2013-09-21 ((2456557j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
d.next_year # => #<Date: 2014-09-21 ((2456922j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Thanks. Mattherick's solution was even more obvious this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_invoices
  User.all.each do |user|
    date = Date.today
    10.times do
      user.invoices.create!(:number => user.next_invoice_number, 
                            :date   => (date += 1.year))
    end
  end
end
```

Because you have `date = Date.today` in the `10.times` loop, it will be reseted in each loop. Just move `date = Date.today` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `Date#next_year`, which takes a parameter meaning how many years you want to advance :

```
def make_invoices
  User.all.each do |user|
    10.times.with_object(Date.today) do |i, date|
      user.invoices.create!(
        number: user.next_invoice_number, 
        date: date.next_year(i)
      )
    end
  end
end
```

`Numeric#times` pass an index to block.

`Enumerator#with_object` allow to pass additional parameters to block, which we here use to avoid setting a local variable outside the block (since we don't need it outside).